# Iptables: "-p udp --state ESTABLISHED"

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, iptables, udp

let's look at these two iptables rules which are often used to allow outgoing DNS:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 1024:65535 --dport 53 
   -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 53 --dport 1024:65535
   -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

My question is: How exactly should I understand the ESTABLISHED state in UDP? UDP is stateless.

**Here is my intuition - I'd like to know, if or where this is incorrect:**

The man page tells me this:

> **state**
>
> ```
> This module, when combined with connection tracking, allows access to the
> connection tracking state for this packet.
>
>   --state ...
> ```

So, iptables basically remembers the port number that was used for the outgoing packet *(what else could it remember for a UDP packet?)*, and then allows the first incoming packet that is sent back within a short timeframe? An attacker would have to guess the port number *(would that really be too hard?)*

About avoiding conflicts:

The kernel keeps track of which ports are blocked (either by other services, or by previous outgoing UDP packets), so that these ports will not be used for new outgoing DNS packets within the timeframe? *(What would happen, if I accidentally tried to start a service on that port within the timeframe - would that attempt be denied/blocked?)*

Please find all errors in the above text :-).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> So, iptables basically remembers the
>   port number that was used for the
>   outgoing packet (what else could it
>   remember for a UDP packet?),

I am pretty sure for UDP the source and destination ports and addresses are stored.

If you want to inspect the state tables install conntrack and/or netstat-nat.

> (What would happen, if I accidentally
>   tried to start a service on that port
>   within the timeframe - would that
>   attempt be denied/blocked?)

Since you are using OUTPUT and INPUT your are talking about local services.  The port is already used I don't believe your system will allow you to start up another service since something is already listening on that port.  I guess you could stop the first service and start another if you really wanted to though, in that case the response would probably get to your service.  What the service does with the packet depends on what the contents of the packet is, and what service it is.

Comment: So if I started say a Tomcat instance on port 8080, I'll have a 1:(65535-1023) chance that the startup will fail, if accidentally a DNS query is running on the same port? Or will it just wait until the timeframe expired? How long is the timeframe by default?

Comment: On Linux I believe the ephemeral port range is commonly 32768-61000 (see /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range) this wouldn't include your example port of 8080.  It tends to be very uncommon to setup services to listen on ports within the ephemeral range.  The time a UDP entry states in the table is typically 30 seconds (see /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_udp_timeout)

Comment: In case any one wishes to extend the udp_timeout, use `echo "net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_udp_timeout = 180" >> /etc/sysctl.conf`

Comment: It seems to that `udp dpt:ntp ctstate NEW` breaks NTP's manycast in SLES15 SP2; at least it works when I disable the firewall.

Comment: @U.Windl  yeah I don't think the stateful are generally useful for broadcast/multicast traffic.

Answer (score 8):

NB: This answer has been edited.

Despite what the man pages say, `ESTABLISHED` appears to mean "stateful".  For UDP that simply means (as you suggest) remembering each outbound UDP packet (the "src ip, src port dst ip, dst port" tuple) for a while and recognising its responses.

FWIW, my normal rules for DNS traffic would be something like this:

```
# permit any outbound DNS request (NB: TCP required too)
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 1024:65535 --dport 53  -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 1024:65535 --dport 53  -j ACCEPT

# accept any packet that's a response to anything we sent
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

i.e. control traffic on the `OUTPUT` chain, and then let the `iptables` state modules handle everything else on the `INPUT` chain.

See also [this related question](https://serverfault.com/questions/110645/iptables-rules-for-caching-nameserver).

Comment: I'm aware that I should allow TCP, too. But what would RELATED mean for UDP? Manpage: "RELATED meaning that the packet is starting a new connection, but is associated with an existing connection, ..." Connections for UDP? Maybe it really makes more sense than ESTABLISHED, but that's what I'd like to find out.

Comment: When I use your rules, but restrict udp INPUT to RELATED, my DNS queries don't work. Seems that I have to allow ESTABLISHED. Is there any reason to also allow RELATED (for UDP)?

Comment: ok, it seems that ESTABLISHED means more than the man page says.  In any event, if you use OUTPUT filters like mine and don't accept inbonud traffic then that INPUT rule is the only one you'll ever need.

Comment: Yeah, the man page is really unclear about these things. But as long as I don't know, if there's any way for an attacker to create a RELATED udp packet (if anything like that exists?) more easily than an ESTABLISHED one, I'd rather be careful with allowing that. My guess is, that RELATED udp packets simply don't exist - in which case your rules are absolutely ok. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Given what we've found, RELATED udp packets don't exist AFAIK.  However (for example) if you ever do _outbound_ FTP from that box you need a RELATED state rule for the data channel.  The single "ESTABLISHED,RELATED" rule is AFAIK the most optimal single rule for ingress traffic.

Comment: actually, `RELATED` UDP packets _might_ exist for RTP.

Answer (score 2):

The iptables developers have considered that an "ESTABLISHED" state was the situation when packets have been seen in both directions whatever the protocol between two clients.

the state extension is part of conntrack. The kernel understands the state from table

```
/proc/net/nf_conntrack
```

Example of iptable states for UDP in table nf_conntrack from sender point of view. Let's imagine you send a DNS query on UDP

```
udp   17 20 src=192.168.1.2 dst=192.168.1.10 sport=35237 dport=53 \
 [UNREPLIED] src=192.168.1.10 dst=192.168.1.2 sport=53 \
 dport=35237 use=1
```

A packet has been sent. It unreplied and oh, the table has the data for what is expected in return (the packet for the DNS answer).

```
udp   17 20 src=192.168.1.2 dst=192.168.1.10 sport=35237 dport=53 \
  src=192.168.1.10 dst=192.168.1.2 sport=53 \
 dport=35237 use=1
```

The reply is arrived, the unreplied flag is gone, it means this UDP connection is in ESTABLISHED state for a small amount of time defined in your system.

Answer (score 1):

Its a common misconception about UDP, most of the people get confused between STATE-LESS and CONNECTION-LESS. UDP is connectionless but its session is stored in the session table of TCPIP stack and the same is used by iptables and conntrack.

Comment: Can you describe what makes up a "session" at both ends?

Comment: @U.Windl in [TCP the 3 way handshake](https://www.google.com/search?q=tcp+3+way+handshake).  SYN -> SYN+ACK -> ACK.

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to "...UDP is connectionless but its session...", i.e.: **UDP**. What makes up a UDP session in your opinion?